# How to update data between components?

Tags: reactjs

[Image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOKLB.png)I'm trying to create a website using the movie DB API. I've created a carousel with some movies and want to open a new page with comprehensive information about a movie by clicking on the movie poster. I'm using componentDidMount to fetch data in one component to create a UI and I pass a movie ID to another component where I use componentWillReceiveProps to fetch another data by using the ID. It worked until I started using state, so now it shows two arrays in the console before I click on a movie poster and when I click on a  poster it shows an array and loads a movie data from API then if I click on another poster it loads two different objects with the previous and current movie. I found out that componentWillReceiveProps is dangerous to use but componentDidUpdate works in the same manner.
The main idea is when a user clicks on a poster it gets its id and sends it to another component where the id goes to a link
with complete information about the movie. Are there any patterns to achieve it?

```
class Data extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: [],
    movieId: null
  };

  onClick = e => {
    this.setState({
      movieId: e.target.id
    });
    console.log(e.target.id);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        let movies = data.results.map(item => {
          return (
            <Link to="/movieInfo"> 
                <div className="overlay" onClick={this.onClick}>
                  <img
                    src= 
                    {`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${item.poster_path}`}
                    alt={item.title}
                    id={item.id}
                   />
                </div>
              </Link> 
             );
        });

        this.setState({
          movies: movies
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

render() {
    const { movies, movieId } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="carousel">
        <Slider movie={movies} />
        <div className="notShow">
          <AdditionalInfo id={movieId} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AdditionalInfo extends Component {
  state = {
    movie: []
  };
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.id !== null && prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
      fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${
          prevProps.id
        }?api_key=81f382d33088c6d52099a62eab51d967&language=en-US`
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>
          this.setState({
            movie: data
          })
        );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { movie } = this.state;
    console.log(movie);
    return (
      <div className="movieInfo-container">
        {/* <section className="title" />
        <section className="cast">{movie.id}</section> */}
        work
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
let movieArr = [];

class Slider extends Component {
  state = {
    currentIndex: 0,
    translateValue: 0
  };

  createNestedArr = () => {
    while (this.props.movie.length) {
      movieArr.push(this.props.movie.splice(0, 5));
    }
    return movieArr.map((item, i) => {
      return <Slide key={i} movieGroup={item} />;
    });
  };

  nextPic = () => {
    if (this.state.currentIndex === movieArr.length - 1) {
      return this.setState({
        currentIndex: 0,
        translateValue: 0
      });
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentIndex: prevState.currentIndex + 1,
      translateValue: prevState.translateValue - this.slideWidth()
    }));
  };

  prevPic = () => {
    if (this.state.currentIndex === movieArr.length + 1) {
      return this.setState({
        currentIndex: 0,
        translateValue: 0
      });
    } else if (this.state.currentIndex === 0) {
      return this.setState({
        currentIndex: 0,
        translateValue: 0
      });
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentIndex: prevState.currentIndex - 1,
      translateValue: prevState.translateValue + this.slideWidth()
    }));
  };

  slideWidth = () => {
    return document.querySelector(".new-releases-slide").clientWidth;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div
          className="movie-carousel"
          style={{
            transform: `translateX(${this.state.translateValue}px)`,
            transition: "transform ease-out 0.45s"
          }}
        >
          {this.createNestedArr()}
        </div>
        <LeftArrow prevPic={this.prevPic} />
        <RightArrow nextPic={this.nextPic} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const Slide = props => {
  const { movieGroup } = props;
  return <div className="new-releases-slide">{movieGroup}</div>;
};
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you provided. Could your provide a screenshot or console.log of your AdditionalInfo state when you click on a new poster?

Comment: If you are using React 16.8, the [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook is what you need.

Comment: I added a screenshot. But componentDidUpdate works really weird, I think it's because of the statement.

Comment: which url do you use to get the data in the parent component

Comment: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=81f382d33088c6d52099a62eab51d967&language=en-US&page=1`

Comment: please share the code for slider.

Comment: I added the slider component

Comment: Slide component is missing

Comment: I added but I don’t think it’s necessary.

Comment: in `/movieInfo/` you use `AdditionalInfo` component?

Comment: @JuniusL. Yes. Should I use context api?

Comment: @IlyaSolodeev no you don't,I'll  add an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `componentDidMount` in your `AdditionalIno` component. You need to pass the id of the clicked movie to `MovieInfo` component. This `<Link to="/movieInfo">` needs to `<Link to={'/movieInfo/${item.id}'}>` and in your `MovieInfo` component access the id using `const { id } = this.props.match.params;`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

class AdditionalInfo extends Component {

  state = {
    movie: [],
    isLoading: true,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { id } = this.props;

    if (!id) {
      return;
    }

    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=81f382d33088c6d52099a62eab51d967&language=en-US`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          movie: data,
          isLoading: false,
        })
      );

  }

  render() {
    const { movie } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="movieInfo-container">
        {this.state.isLoading

          ? <Loader type="Puff" color="#00BFFF" height="100" width="100" />
          : <div><section className="title" />
            <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
            <section className="cast">ID: {movie.id}</section>
            <h2>Overview</h2>
            <p>{movie.overview}</p></div>

        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdditionalInfo;
```

then in your `Data` component change your `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount = () => {

  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      let movies = data.results.map(item => {
        return (
          <Link to={`/movieInfo/${item.id}`}> 
              <div className="overlay" onClick={this.onClick}>
                <img
                  src= 
                  {`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${item.poster_path}`}
                  alt={item.title}
                  id={item.id}
                />
              </div>
            </Link> 
          );
      });

      this.setState({
        movies: movies
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

In your `MovieInfo` do something like

```
class MovieInfo extends Component {

  render() {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    return (
      <div>
        <AdditionalInfo id={id} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Your router should be like

```
<Route path="/movieInfo/:id" exact component={MovieInfo} />
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ukpsej)

Comment: you were not passing the id of clicked movie to `MovieInfo`  `to="/movieInfo"`

Comment: I used `<Link to={'/movieInfo/${item.id}'}>` to add id as a parameter and access it in movieinfo component.